# How do you convert a two dimensional array of a boxed type to a two dimensional array of the corresponding primitive type?

Tags: java

```
Integer[][] documents = { {1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 6},
        {2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2},
        {1, 6, 5, 6, 0, 1, 6, 5, 6, 0, 1, 6, 5, 6, 0, 0},
        {5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 2, 2, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 0},
        {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        {5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}};
int[][] convertDocument = documents;
```

the compiler says incompatible types: Integer[][] cannot be converted to int[][]...
how to solve this?

Comment: There isn't a convenient way or inbuild method, you have to do it via nested for loops.

Comment: Yup.  You have to loop through it in a nested loop and use something like   for (Integer[] integers : documents) {for (Integer integer : integers) {}} as your loop.  Inside your nested loop you'll then convert the Integer to an int and assign it.

Comment: I'm curious... why you aren't using something like an ArrayList?

Comment: Reopen. Not a duplicate. I didn't see any answers pertaining to 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the list and convert each element into an int primitive. Arrays are special kinds of objects in Java, so `int[][]` and `Integer[][]` are completely unrelated to each other. It would be like trying to cast a `Foo` to a `Bar`. Java *does* support implicit casts from `Integer` to `int` however. That's called auto-boxing, and you can see it at work below at the line `primitives[i][j] = documents[i][j]` where a single `Integer` is implicitly cast to a primitive `int`.

```
int[][] convertToPrimitives(Integer[][] documents) {
    int[][] primitives = new int[documents.length][];
    for (int i=0;i<documents.length;i++) {
        primitives[i] = new int[documents[i].length];
        for (int j=0;j<documents[i].length;j++) {
            primitives[i][j] = documents[i][j];
        }
    }
    return primitives;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the sixth line of your code.

Comment: You are assuming that it is a matrix. It does not seem to be a matrix.